# Expandable ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I am trying to create Expanable listview. Which has format of Menu - sub menu and sub menu of sub menu and then the items. Also few Menu don't have sub menus.

All this on navigation Drawer (Side Menu)...

I am reffering to something like this:

[image]

Question is:

1. How do i implement this kind of design? Will Expandable Listview help achieve this?
2. any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/07/android-multilevel-expandable-listview.html - check this...hope it helps give you some idea

Comment: I want this implemented on navigation drawer?

Comment: for that in expandable adapter  inside getchildview() you  have to implement a new expandable listvieew.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create some kind of tree data structure and there store your items.

Nodes will be your sections and subsections, while leafs the actual data. This will allow you to track a visibility state of each item (basically if it is in an expanded or in a collapsed section)

Then create an adapter with 2 viewtypes: `Category` and `Item`.
Its `getItemViewType` method should return `Item` type for each `leaf` and `Category` for each `node`.
Its `getCount` should return a total count of all sections + subsections + items.
Its `getView` should return an actual view according to its type, but the important thing is to check whether or not is it contained in an expanded (!and also visible - you need to check for it recursively) section and accordingly set its `visibility` to either `VISIBLE` or `GONE`. 
Its `onItemClicked` should toggle its state between expanded and collapsed for Sections. A Sections object should probably have a method able to tell you if is it expanded and if is it visible (if parent is expanded, or top level,..)

*Sorry for no code here, this should help you to get an idea, I was in hurry to write some example (it requires quite a lot of code)*